# Installing/downloading packages

Tags: packages, installing

I am an absolute beginner to LaTeX. And I'm following the [Wikibooks tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/).  I am at the part where it talks about packages. It doesn't really explain where to download and install them. So where do I? In the tutorial, they're using the *mathptmx* and *pifont*.

I am using ShareLaTeX, if that matters.

Comment: ShareLaTeX being an online editor, I would think there is no support or if there is, you are not required to do any more than just `\usepackage{}`.

Comment: That is, put `\usepackage{mathptmx}` and `\usepackage{pifont}` before the line `\begin{document}`.  'LaTeX' will know how to do the rest.

Comment: Seriously? I don't have to download these "packages"

Comment: I haven't used ShareLaTeX, but the [FAQ](https://www.sharelatex.com/faq) says it includes a full installation of TeX Live 2011, which certainly includes `pifont` and `mathptmx`.  Of course, if you want to do real work with LaTeX (or ConTeXt, etc.), you might consider installing TeX Live on your computer (if you use windows, MikTeX is another possibility).

Answer (score 2):

In share latex you will not have to do anything other than specifying the package you want.

If you want to work locally without a constant internet access, I would recommend using MikTeX for package handling, it will do it automatically, and TeXmaker for typing and previewing as it will let you have a preview window open and you can just click in it and it jumps to the relevant latex code.